# Signal 15 terminating

Tags: linux, signals

I am facing this particular problem. My system is switching from multi user mode to single user mode automatically right after

This error (`signal 15 terminating`). The detail of log messages is below. I have the following questions:

1. Why would this error have occurred?
2. How to bring the system back to multi suer mode from single user mode

```
    var/log/messages
    auditd[2460]: The audit daemon is now changing the system to single user mode 
    init: Switching to runlevel:1 
    sshd[4945]: Accepted public key from user 200.x.x.x
    sshd[7927]: Received signal 15; terminating 
    xinetd[2591]: Exiting 
    auditd[2460]: The audit daemon is exiting 
    Kernel log daemon terminating 
    Exiting on signal 15
```

Answer (score 2):

your system is being switched by your audit daemon which is happening in the first line of your log not the  exiting on sig 15

I'd check the space on your disk ( and also look at the audit daemon config  ) as the "single" option for "space left " will cause the audit daemon to change you to single user mode.

if you don't need the audit daemon i'd turn it off. if you do check its config.

on Ubuntu the config file is /etc/audit/auditd.conf 
if you are using another linux flavor it may be in a different location

Comment: Thank you General Foch for the help. It was really helpful.